# What happens on ARM when double to int64_t conversion overflows?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, floating-point-conversion

With x86 you get the magic value `1 << 63` (MSB set, rest clear, i.e. the most-negative number, which Intel calls the "integer indefinite" value) when you convert a `double` to an `int64_t` with the x87 FPU, SSE or AVX, when the result of rounding to an integer isn't in range.  In addition to that, the invalid operation FP exception is raised.

Is there a similar behaviour with ARM? That would be nice because I need portability only to x86 and ARM.

Comment: In case it matters, which FPU are you using on ARM?  NEON, or one of the older vFP things?

Comment: The reference manual defines pseudocode. In this case it's the ```FPToFixed``` function. Looks like it assigns with signed or unsigned saturation. But my interpretation could be wrong. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2022-03/Shared-Pseudocode/Shared-Functions?lang=en

Comment: But for your specific ARM architecture, you have to check with its architecture reference manual. I just picked AArch64